# Is there any API for okta verify app to get the access code or accept the push?

Tags: automation, okta, multi-factor-authentication

Use Case:
In our product, we are using okta verify as MFA. we need to automate the MFA process, where we need to get the access code and submit the code for verification or accept the push to complete the verification process.

Challenges:
Okta verify is sitting on Android or IOS, so we can not include the devices in our environment and make them work

Need:
Is there any API to get the access code or accept the push?

Comment: I am starting an MFA project with okta and would like to know if you ever got this figured out. If so can you let me know the information so I can research the process I need? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this ?
[Okta SDK](https://developer.okta.com/docs/guides/sign-into-mobile-app-redirect/android/main/)

They explain for Android and iOS how to include Okta identification in your app.